# im trying to load a grid view ,a tree , and 3 combobox from one table in spring hibernate but my data geting damaged

Tags: spring, hibernate, session

my project have a big problem with loading data more than once from a table in document ready.when i try to load my grid ,tree, 3 combo-box from one table sometimes my tree or my grid receiving null data.sometimes showing empty fields
and when I'm trying to save or delete from that table glass-fish shows error "null" just null; 
i using one session to do all my stuffs and i tried to close and open that session or clean it but it doesn't worked. I don't know what the problem is.please somebody help me.
thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider providing a minimal working example of the problem.  It's hard to give specific solutions to general statements.

I know you referenced GlassFish and sessions, so you clearly have a server side to this, but you also reference combo box.

If you're working in Swing, it is critical that all updates to GUI elements are done on the event dispatch thread:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

On the server side, if you have any concurrency, objects in session will need to be thread-safe.  Since concurrency is assumed, please make sure all objects in session are thread safe and always represent a consistent state.

For example, if you build a list of objects, consider two options:

1. Fill-in a list then add to session - the session will always contain a complete list and concurrent requests will always get a complete view.
2. Add list to session when fill-in the list - this will have a race condition where concurrent requests many see incomplete or partial data.

Think of what goes into session as "transactional" - consistent sets of data in.

I'm just rambling, tell us more and we can tell you more.